# Unfortunately My App has Stopped working due to nullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get images from the server and load them into gridview but My App is not responding.I am using picasso library to load the images.

This is my ImageAdapter class

```
package com.example.haha;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    int length;
    String[] poster_paths=null;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
        new BackgroundTask().execute();
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return length;
        }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        //ImageView image;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView==null)
        convertView=(ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridviewitem, null);



        Picasso.with(context)  //USING PICASSO LIBRARY
        .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/"+ poster_paths[position]) 
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .into((ImageView)convertView);

        return convertView;
    }


    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>{


        final String BASE_URL="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?"
                + "sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=b6c282dc7fb604515fdcf8d8cf56e761";


         private String[] jsonParse(String movieJsonStr) throws JSONException{

            final String POSTER_PATH="poster_path";  //JSON STRING PARSING AND RETURN 
                                                     //POSTER PATHS

            JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(movieJsonStr);
            JSONArray resultArray= jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

            length=resultArray.length();
            String[] poster_paths= new String[length];
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                poster_paths[i]=resultArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(POSTER_PATH);
            }

            for(String res : poster_paths)
            Log.v(POSTER_PATH, res);    

            return poster_paths;
        }


        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            String movieJsonStr = null;

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null; // READ THE INPUTSTREAM AND
                                                    // GET THE JSONSTRING
            try {
                URL url = new URL(BASE_URL);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it
                    // won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print
                    // out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }

                movieJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                Log.v("Movie string: ", movieJsonStr);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.e("backgroundtask", "EXCEPTION", e);
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("READER.CLOSE()", e.toString());
                }
            }

            try {
                return jsonParse(movieJsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("BACKGROUNDTASK", "EXCEPTION FROM jsonParse()", e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            if(result!=null)
            poster_paths=result;
            }

        }

}
```

and this is my logcat

```
08-01 03:04:56.108: D/AndroidRuntime(2588): Shutting down VM
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588): Process: com.example.haha, PID: 2588
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at com.example.haha.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:62)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1060)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
08-01 03:04:56.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-01 03:04:56.109: W/ActivityManager(1226):   Force finishing activity com.example.haha/.Main
08-01 03:04:56.110: W/ActivityManager(1226):   Force finishing activity com.example.haha/.MainActivity
```

the logcat is saying that there is a nullpointerException while accessing the string array poster_paths in getView method as it is a null array but in the postexecute method the poster_paths array is assigned the strings 
Please help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youre [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable `poster_paths`. Replace

```
String[] poster_paths= new String[length];
```

with

```
posterPaths = new String[length];
```

Comment: thanks a lot it is working!!!! But i still cant understand as                                 String[] poster_paths= new String[length]; is in another method and poster_paths=result; in onPostExecute method is getting the string.Then how it is shadowed

Comment: basically only the variable in the scope of the `jsonParse` method is initialized & the variable at class level remains uninitialized since you've declared another variable with same name in the method.

Comment: but why as OnPostExecute() method runs on ui thread and  poster_paths here poster_paths=result should be the class variable also the scope of String[] poster_paths= new String[length]; ends with jsonParse()

Comment: The result of `doInBackground` is passed to `onPostExecute`. You are passing `null`

Comment: Reimeus Sorry I am not able to understand can you please elaborate

Comment: One of your code paths in `doInBackground` is returning `null`. You need to debug the method to see where this is happening